# Intune SDK integration for an iOS app with target as iOS 9

Tags: ios, intune

As per this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/developer/app-sdk-ios#prerequisites), app integrating Intune SDK must have target as iOS 11 or above. However, I had previously integrated Intune SDK for an app targeting iOS 10.

Now, I want to integrate Intune SDK to an existing app targeted to iOS 9. Is it possible? May be an older version of the SDK?

Comment: Hi Vaibhav, can you please help me to wrap ios app using intune sdk.

Comment: Hi Ashish, I didn't wrap but included the SDK in my app. However, the documentation is pretty clear. Let me know what issue you are facing. Btw you can post your question on their Github repo as well: https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/ms-intune-app-sdk-ios/issues

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav...I've integrated Intune SDK. Now in-the-process of uploading ipa on intune.